# How to write a regex expression that'll allow me to match and replace either a hostname or ip adress

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression that'll allow me to take a string such as

```
https://10.1.10.10:8080/abc?
```

so here i want to extract and manipulate the 10.1.10.10 portion

Or

```
https://www.google.com:80808/abc?
```

and here i would like the www.google.com part

currently I have it being able to do this with the IP address but whenever it comes to doing it with the hostname I cant figure out how to stop the "https/http" portion from interfering along with the "8080" and "abc". I'm hoping this will allow me to use regex.replace to easily swap out the Host portion of the URI.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: In what context/language? PHP: Start with parse_url. JavaScript: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: Just use Uri class, no need for regex here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and change the [Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.host(v=vs.110).aspx) part:

```
String[] strings = {"https://10.1.10.10:8080/abc?", "https://www.google.com:8080/abc?"};
foreach (string s in strings)
{
    var b = new UriBuilder(s);
    b.Host = "test";
    Console.WriteLine(b.Uri.ToString());
}
```

[Demo C#](http://rextester.com/APNO65473)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
^[^:]+:\/\/([^:\/]+)
```

Then access the first capture group.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var url = @"https://www.google.com:80808/abc?";
var replacement = "hey there";
var regex = new Regex( @"^(\w+://)(?:.*?)(:\d+/\w+\W)$" );
var updated = regex.Replace( url, $"$1{replacement}$2" );
```